# how can I use variable in xlswrite?

Tags: matlab

That's my code:

```
sub = num2str(sub);
run = num2str(run); 
xlswrite('./Dataset/Sub', num2str(sub), '_list.xls')"
```

It does not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the error you get? You're likely going to need `[]` around the parts of the string that make up the `xls` filename to join them together

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are passing each part of the file path string as a separate argument to [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html). You need to concatenate the strings together into a single string, then pass that as a single argument. There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
fileStr = ['./Dataset/Sub' int2str(sub) '_list.xls'];          % With square brackets
fileStr = strcat('./Dataset/Sub', int2str(sub), '_list.xls');  % With strcat
fileStr = sprintf('./Dataset/Sub%d_list.xls', sub);            % With sprintf
```

Note I used [`int2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int2str.html), since I assume you are dealing with integers. Now you can do this:

```
xlswrite(fileStr, ...other arguments go here... );
```

Some suggested reading: [Creating character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html#bsehgfv-1), [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html), [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)